# ¿Como usar ajax con django forms?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-forms

#### Mi models.py

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from general.models import BaseUnique, BaseTitle, Empresa, Arl
from recurso_humano.models import Persona, Sucursal

# ===================== HEALTH BASIC =========================
TIPO_DOCUMENTO = (
    (1, 'Cédula'),
    (2, 'Nit'),
)

class Especialidad(BaseUnique):
    pass

class ProveedorSalud(models.Model):
    tipo_documento = models.IntegerField(choices=TIPO_DOCUMENTO, verbose_name="tipo de Identificación")
    numero_documento = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name='número de Identificación')
    nombre_completo = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Nombre Completo')
    telefonos = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Teléfono(s)')
    especialidades = models.ManyToManyField(Especialidad, blank=True, through='ProveedorEspecialidad', related_name="esp")

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s"%(self.nombre_completo)).strip() or "-"

class ProveedorEspecialidad(models.Model):
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(ProveedorSalud)
    especialidad = models.ForeignKey(Especialidad)

class DatosExamenMedico(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Nombre Exámen")
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(ProveedorSalud)
    especialidad = models.ForeignKey(Especialidad)
    precio_de_proveedor = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Precio de Proveedor")
    precio_a_cliente = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Precio a Cliente")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("codigo", "nombre"),)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s (%s)"%(self.codigo, self.nombre)).strip() or "-"
```

#### Mi forms.py inicial

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import random, string, os

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django_select2.forms import Select2MultipleWidget, Select2Widget
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget, Select2Widget

from gestion_salud.models import *
from general.models import Empresa, Arl, ActividadEconomica, Empresa_ActividadEconomica

class DatosExamenMedicoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DatosExamenMedico
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
        }

class EspecialidadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Especialidad
        exclude = ()

class ProveedorSaludForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProveedorSaludForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['especialidades'].queryset = Especialidad.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = ProveedorSalud
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
            'especialidades': Select2MultipleWidget()
        }
```

#### Parte de mi views.py

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from gestion_salud.forms import *
from recurso_humano.forms import PersonaForm, PersonaForm_Basico, CedulaForm
from recurso_humano.models import Persona
from recurso_humano.views.gestion_humana import calcular_tipo

@login_required
def examen_medico_crear(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DatosExamenMedicoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            objeto = form.save(commit=False)
            objeto.save()
            request.session['em_creada'] = True
            return redirect('matriz_em')
    else :
        form = DatosExamenMedico_crear_Form()

    return render(request, 'em_crear__salud.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Resulta que si mando el form por defecto para `DatosExamenMedico` puedo seleccionar cualquier `ProveedorSalud` y cualquier `Especialidad`, pero la idea no es esa, sino que seleccione primero el proveedor y automáticamente en el campo `Especialidad` se filtren sólo las especialidades de ese `ProveedorSalud`.

Me han dicho que use ajax, pero no sé cómo buscar la info que necesito ni en español ni en inglés, un ejemplo sería de gran ayuda, así sea de paises-ciudades.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo poner un poco mas de detalles ya que no es claro lo que preguntas, también te recomiendo poner lo que hasta el momento has intentado.

Comment: @Gemasoft no he intentado nada porque no sé cómo hacerlo ni cómo preguntar, pero ahí está mi código por si acaso.

Comment: Correcto, así esta un  poco mejor.

Comment: tienes algo que me recomiendes? aún no tengo lo que necesito

Answer (score 2):

La recomendacion que te dieron es correcta, puedes usar una llamada `ajax` para ir al servidor y recuperar informacion que luego usarias para cargar algun control.

[How do I integrate Ajax with Django applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306981/how-do-i-integrate-ajax-with-django-applications)

No conozco sobre Django, pero en el articulo explica como exponer funcionalidad que luego consumes mediante `$.ajax` de `jquery`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '127.0.0.1:8000/hello',
    type: 'get', 
    success: function(data) {
        //aqui trabajas el data para definir los options del combo
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Got an error dude');
    }
});
```

en el `success` es donde tomaras los datos que podrias enviar con formato `json` para iterar y definir los options del combo.

Tambien ha librerias que podrian ayudar

[django-ajax](https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar django-smart-selects, este es muy sencillo y ya hace todo lo de Jquery por ti.

https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Comment: Yo he utilizado django-smart-selects y me ha funcionado bastante bien, aunque hay otras opciones, como lo que te propone Lenadro y otras personas con ajax. Aca un pequeño acercamiento https://axiacore.com/blog/django-y-selects-encadenados/

Comment: Este es otro recurso https://creativosweb.com.ve/programacion/peticiones-ajax-en-django-con-jquery/, yo no los he probado y confieso que manejar ajax y django es un tema pendiente que tengo. Hay que tener siempre pendiente el uso del token como se ilustra allí.